# TV streaming with HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) or RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol) on the iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, streaming, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I was wondering, is it possible to stream a TV channel (if I had a TV channel as customer to provide me the data) on the iPad using HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) or RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol)?

I've read the Wikipedia's page on both **[HLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming)** and
**[RSTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol)** and ended up on a page about a **[Helix Universal Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix_Universal_Server)** which supports delivery of data with both protocols.

That being said, my question is specifically about TV streaming. Is it possible to stream TV with any of those protocols? **If not**, what protocol should be used?

And **more importantly**, are TV streaming apps allowed on the App Store?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can most certainly provide a live video feed to iDevices via HLS. [WowzaMediaServer](http://www.wowza.com/), and [IIS 7.0](http://www.iis.net/media) both support outputting a video stream to HLS format (much like Helix, as you mention). Provided you have the rights for rebroadcasting the content - I don't see any challenges with this.

When you state "stream tv" - it is the same as any other live video input - the only challenge here would be gaining the rights to rebroadcast the content.

RTSP is not supported by iDevices (iPad, iPod, iPhone).

To answer your "more importantly" question - you need to do a little research. I think it's pointless to say yes or no, as things can always change.

Here's a link to the App Store Review Guidelines: [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use gstreamill: http://github.com/i4tv/gstreamill

- hls, http progressive streaminig, udp output.
- hls push mode output via webdav.
- Multi-Rate with GOP Alignment.
- RESTful management interface, allowing easy integration into operator environment.
- Job is descript in json.
- Job run in subprocess, and auto restart on error.
- Base on gstreamer and easy to extend.